# partial sums after group by in data.table

Tags: r, group-by, data.table

Let us assume we are provided with the following data:

```
library(data.table)

letters <- sample (LETTERS[1:6], 100, replace = TRUE) 
quarks  <- sample(c("up", "down", "charme", "strange", "top", "bottom"), 
                  100, replace = TRUE)
measures<- sample(seq(1:6), 100, replace = TRUE)

df <- data.frame(letters, quarks, measures)
df <- data.table(df)
df <- df[,.(count = sum(measures)), by = list(letters, quarks)] 
df

     letters  quarks   count
 ---------------------------
 1:       A   bottom    13
 2:       A   charme     3
 3:       A     down    14
 4:       A  strange     8
 5:       A      top    11
 6:       A       up    14
 7:       B   bottom     8
 8:       B   charme    12
 9:       B     down     3
```

essentially we count how many observations we have in correspondence of each quark and each letter, grouping by using the `[.,]` function provided by the library `data.table`.

**Question:** I would like to accompany this with a new column showing the total count of measures per letter, so that each quark is normalised to how many there are having the same letter. In particular this can be singularly obtained by:

```
df[,.(count = sum(measures)), by = letters]

    letters count
1:       F    54
2:       E    65
3:       B    71
4:       D    36
5:       C    82
6:       A    45
```

In this way each count for each single quark can be divided and normalised to how many total quarks we have associated to the same letter. Is there a way to achieve this still using `data.table`?

Comment: Please use `set.seed` before generating a random example data set.

Comment: Oh yes, sure, my bad. However the actual counts don't really matter here.

Comment: Just makes it easier to verify that we're getting the right results.

Comment: Also, not sure if you want to change the title, but "partial sum" has a particular meaning in math that is different from what you're doing here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_sum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that by chaining a new summarisation in which you only group by `letters` to your first summarisation as follows:

```
dfnew <- df[,.(count = sum(measures)), by = list(letters, quarks)
            ][, lettercount := sum(count) , by = letters]
```

this gives:

```
> dfnew
    letters  quarks count lettercount
 1:       A strange    16          30
 2:       A    down     8          30
 3:       A     top     5          30
 4:       A  charme     1          30
 5:       B strange    13          43
 6:       B  bottom     9          43
 7:       B     top    14          43
 8:       B  charme     6          43
 9:       B    down     1          43
10:       C  charme    24          73
11:       C      up     7          73
12:       C    down    11          73
13:       C strange    18          73
14:       C     top     3          73
15:       C  bottom    10          73
16:       D    down     8          41
17:       D  charme     3          41
18:       D  bottom     7          41
19:       D      up    10          41
20:       D strange     4          41
21:       D     top     9          41
22:       E  charme    12          77
23:       E      up     8          77
24:       E     top     8          77
25:       E strange    21          77
26:       E  bottom    13          77
27:       E    down    15          77
28:       F  bottom    14          45
29:       F    down    11          45
30:       F      up    10          45
31:       F strange     8          45
32:       F  charme     2          45
```

If you want a ratio (like @Arun showed in his answer) instead of the sum by letter, you can replace `lettercount := sum(count)` by `ratio := count/sum(count)`.

---

Used data:

```
set.seed(1)
letters <- sample (LETTERS[1:6], 100, replace = TRUE) 
quarks  <- sample(c("up", "down", "charme", "strange", "top", "bottom"), 
                  100, replace = TRUE)
measures<- sample(seq(1:6), 100, replace = TRUE)

df <- data.table(letters, quarks, measures)[order(letters)]
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of the possibility to chain the `[.,]`. It is quite powerful indeed!

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to *group within each group* using `.SD` as follows:

```
require(data.table)
ans = df[, .(ratio=.SD[, .(tmp=sum(measures)), by=quarks]$tmp/sum(measures)), by=letters]
head(ans)
#    letters      ratio
# 1:       C 0.20588235
# 2:       C 0.13235294
# 3:       C 0.35294118
# 4:       C 0.04411765
```

I still prefer the answer shown by @Jaap, except we can directly obtain the ratio instead of creating the *lettercount* column.

Comment: Probably want a `quarks` col in the result as well, and maybe to add a `# ...` line to clarify that the result has more rows.

Comment: I thought about that too; however, in this way one doesn't have the categorisation by quark name (that instead appears piping the two `[.,]`), does one?

Comment: My version was `count_df <- df[,{
 n_let    = sum(measures);
 temp_df  = .SD[ , .(n_letq = sum(measures)), by=quarks];
 c(
  temp_df, 
  list(
   n_let   = n_let,
   frac_letq  = temp_df$n_letq/n_let
  )
 )
}, by=letters]` but I figured it was too long and fugly to post.